# How to iterate through vector and replace values in R

Tags: r, merge, key, lookup

it's a fairly simple task, but I'm trying to wrap my head around how to match values using a dataframe with keys and values. I've tried merge, but as the number of rows is different, I'm not sure that's appropriate.

Is there a for loop I can write that will loop through each key in my input dataframe and change Product's value if it's one of the ones in the lookup table?

Essentially, my data looks like this:

`input_key <- c(9061,8680,1546,5376,9550,9909,3853,3732,9209)
    input_product <- c("Water", "Bread", NA, "Chips", "Chicken", NA, "Chocolate", "Donuts", "Juice")
    input <- as.data.frame(cbind(input_key, input_product))`

I'd like to replace the NAs with the Product values in the corresponding lookup table:

```
lookup_key <- c(1245,1546, 7764, 9909)
lookup_product <- c("Ice Cream","Soda", "Bacon","Cheese")
lookup_data <- as.dataframe(cbind(lookup_key, lookup_product))
```

Finally, I'm hoping to get the final dataframe looking like this:

```
output_key <- c(9061,8680,1546,5376,9550,9909,3853,3732,9209)
output_product <- c("Water", "Bread", "Soda", "Chips", "Chicken", "Cheese", Chocolate","Donuts", "Juice")
output_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(output_key, output_product))
```

Comment: probably best not to use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` unless you want your variables to be factors. Use `data.frame()` instead.

Comment: I've tried subsetting using [], and I think probably because the variables are factors, R has been throwing errors.

I've tried using dplyr combining filter and replace, but ideally, I'd like to iterate through an entire dataframe so that I don't have to replace each separate value (the real dataset is a few thousand rows).

Comment: There is something wrong with your sample data.  The input and output_data data.frames are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1**: Using R-base functions:

*Vectorial solution:*

```
input$input_product[input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key == TRUE] <- 
    lookup_product[lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key == TRUE]
```

*Note:* The `==TRUE` is redundant, added just for better understanding.

*Using `lapply` function:*

```
idx <- input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key
lapply((1:nrow(input)),
    function(i) {
        if (idx[i] == TRUE) {
            jdx <- lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key[i]
            input$input_product[i] <<- lookup_data$lookup_product[jdx == TRUE]
        }
    }
)
```

*Note:* Attention to the global assignment operation (`<<`)

*Using `for` loop:*

```
idx <- input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key
for (i in (1:nrow(input))) {
    if (idx[i] == TRUE) {
        jdx <- lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key[i]
        input$input_product[i] <- lookup_data$lookup_product[jdx == TRUE]
    }
}
```

*Note:* Here we just need a simple assignment.

In the above cases you need to create the data frames setting the input argument: `stringsAsFactors` as `FALSE`, for example:

```
input <- as.data.frame(cbind(input_key, input_product), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lookup_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(lookup_key, lookup_product), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you get the output:

```
> input
  input_key input_product
1      9061         Water
2      8680         Bread
3      1546          Soda
4      5376         Chips
5      9550       Chicken
6      9909        Cheese
7      3853     Chocolate
8      3732        Donuts
9      9209         Juice
>
```

**OPTION 2**: Using `data.table`package

I found this *elegant* solution using inner join:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(input,input_key)
setkey(lookup_data,lookup_key)
> setDT(input)[setDT(lookup_data), input_product := i.lookup_product, nomatch=0][]
 input_key input_product
1:      1546          Soda
2:      3732        Donuts
3:      3853     Chocolate
4:      5376         Chips
5:      8680         Bread
6:      9061         Water
7:      9209         Juice
8:      9550       Chicken
9:      9909        Cheese
>
```

`data.table`is actually very powerful for data set manipulation. Let's explain the syntax behind:

- `setDT`: Converts a data frame by reference (no copy occurs) into `data.table`, because the original data sets are not a `data.table` classes, that's the way to
     convert them on the fly. Notice that now it is not necessary to use the attribute `stringsAsFactors` because for `data.table`its default value is `FALSE`.
- `input[lookup_data, nomatch=0]`: Is the way, with `data.table` package to create a inner join (see this [link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html)). It means the interception of both tables. The `no match` option with value `0` means no rows will be returned for that row of i (in our case: `lookup_data`).

This would be the output:

```
> setDT(input)[setDT(lookup_data), nomatch=0][]
   input_key input_product lookup_product
   1:      1546            NA           Soda
   2:      9909            NA         Cheese
   >
```

- `input_product := i.lookup_product`: assigns the column from the outer
  data set, with the value of the inner data set.
- `[]`: Prints the result (for verifying the solution purpose)

For more information about `data.table`I would recommend to read the package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) it comes with many examples. It is also a good idea to run in R the following command (after loading the `data.table`package):

```
example(data.table)
```

It provides more than 50 examples (the same from the package documentation) with its corresponding result about the different uses of this package.

**PERFORMANCE**

Let's compare all possible alternatives in terms of performance. Then we need to modify
the input data set for increasing its size:

```
rep.num <- 1000
input_key <- rep(c(9061,8680,1546,5376,9550,9909,3853,3732,9209),rep.num)
input_product <- rep(c("Water", "Bread", NA, "Chips", "Chicken", NA, "Chocolate", 
    "Donuts", "Juice"),rep.num)
input <- as.data.frame(cbind(input_key, input_product), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Wrap all different alternatives into a corresponding given function. I have included 
the solution via `dplyr` proposed by @count

```
vectSol <- function(input, lookup_data) {
    input$input_product[input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key == TRUE] <- 
        lookup_product[lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key == TRUE]
    return(input)
}

lapplySol <- function(input, lookup_data) {
  idx <- input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key
    lapply((1:nrow(input)),
        function(i) {
            if (idx[i] == TRUE) {
                jdx <- lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key[i]
                input$input_product[i] <<- lookup_data$lookup_product[jdx == TRUE]
            }
        }
    )
    return(input)
}

forSol <- function(input, lookup_data) {
   idx <- input$input_key %in% lookup_data$lookup_key
    for (i in (1:nrow(input))) {
        if (idx[i] == TRUE) {
            jdx <- lookup_data$lookup_key %in% input$input_key[i]
            input$input_product[i] <- lookup_data$lookup_product[jdx == TRUE]
        }
    } 
   return(input)
}

dataTableSol <- function (input, lookup_data) {
    setkey(input,input_key)
    setkey(lookup_data,lookup_key)
    input[lookup_data, input_product := i.lookup_product, nomatch=0]
    return(input)
}

dplyrSol <- function(input, lookup_data) {
    rbind(input[!is.na(input$input_product),],
    inner_join(lookup_data,input,by=c("lookup_key"="input_key")) %>% 
    select(lookup_key,lookup_product) %>%
    rename(input_product = lookup_product, input_key = lookup_key))
    return(input)
}
```

Now test each solution (double check).

Make a copy of the input data set, because `data.table` operate by reference. We need to create a copy from scratch.

```
input.copy <- setDT(as.data.frame(cbind(input_key, input_product), stringsAsFactors=F))
lookup_data.copy<- setDT(as.data.frame(cbind(lookup_key, lookup_product), 
    stringsAsFactors=F))

input1.out <- vectSol(input, lookup_data)
input2.out <- lapplySol(input, lookup_data)
input3.out <- forSol(input, lookup_data)
input4.out <- forSol(input, lookup_data)
input5.out <- dataTableSol(copy(input.copy), lookup_data.copy)
```

We use the package `compare` because `all.equal` fails for comparing a data frame 
with a data.table object, because the attributes values, therefore we need a 
comparison that only checks the values.

```
library(compare)
OK <- all(
all.equal(input1.out, input2.out) && all.equal(input1.out, input3.out)
&& all.equal(input1.out, input4.out)
&& compare(input1.out[order(input1.out$input_key),], 
    input5.out, ignoreAttrs=T)$result
)
try(if(!OK) stop("Result are not the same for all methods"))
```

Now let's to use `microbenchmark`package for comparing the time performance of all solutions

```
library(microbenchmark)
op <- microbenchmark(
    VECT = {vectSol(input, lookup_data)},
    FOR = {forSol(input, lookup_data)},
    LAPPLY = {lapplySol(input, lookup_data)},
    DPLYR = {dplyrSol(input, lookup_data)},
    DATATABLE = {dataTableSol(input.copy, lookup_data.copy)},
    times=100L)
print(op)
```

Here is the result:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
      VECT   1.005890   1.078983   1.384964   1.108162   1.282269   6.562040   100  a 
       FOR 416.268583 438.545475 476.551526 449.679426 476.032938 740.027018   100   b
    LAPPLY 428.456092 454.664204 492.918478 464.204607 501.168572 751.786224   100   b
     DPLYR  13.371847  14.919726  16.482236  16.105815  17.086174  23.537866   100  a 
 DATATABLE   1.699995   2.059205   2.427629   2.279371   2.489406   8.542219   100  a
```

Additionally we can graph the solution, via:

```
library(ggplot2) #nice log plot of the output
qplot(y=time, data=op, colour=expr) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: graphical comparison among all alternatives]

The best performance on this order is: Vectorial, data.table, dplyr, for-loop, lapply.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty tired so this is clumsy, but it should work for the data provided (your output sample is probaly wrong though):

```
require(dplyr)

rbind(input[!is.na(input$input_product),],
    inner_join(lookup_data,input,by=c("lookup_key"="input_key")) %>% 
    select(lookup_key,lookup_product) %>%
    rename(input_product = lookup_product, input_key = lookup_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using the **data.table** package as follows:

```
# load sample data
input_data <- structure(list(
    input_key = 
        structure(c(6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 
                    3L, 2L, 7L), 
                  .Label = c("1546", "3732", "3853", "5376", "8680", 
                             "9061", "9209", "9550", "9909"), class = "factor"), 
    input_product = structure(c(7L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                              .Label = c("Bread", "Chicken", "Chips", "Chocolate", 
                                         "Donuts", "Juice", "Water"), class = "factor")), 
    .Names = c("input_key", 
               "input_product"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

lookup_data <- structure(list(
    lookup_key = structure(1:4, 
                           .Label = c("1245", "1546", "7764", "9909"), class = "factor"), 
    lookup_product = structure(c(3L, 
                                 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bacon", "Cheese", "Ice Cream", "Soda"
                                 ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("lookup_key", "lookup_product"
                                 ), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

# convert to data.table and add keys for merging
library(data.table)
input <- data.table(input_data, key = 'input_key')
lookup <- data.table(lookup_data, key = 'lookup_key')

# merge the data (can use merge method as well)
DT <- lookup[input]

# where the input_product is NA, replace with lookup
DT[is.na(input_product), input_product := lookup_product]
print(DT)

# you can now get rid of lookup_product column, if you like
DT[, lookup_product:= NULL]
print(DT)
```

The final output of the above is:

```
> print(DT)
   lookup_key input_product
1:       1546          Soda
2:       3732        Donuts
3:       3853     Chocolate
4:       5376         Chips
5:       8680         Bread
6:       9061         Water
7:       9209         Juice
8:       9550       Chicken
9:       9909        Cheese
```

Comment: I edited my solution to include as second option using `data.table` package. I found a solution in just one single line.

Comment: Yes. Nice enhancement. Cheers